# GWT super-source gives unable to resolve class java/lang/Object in development mode

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to emulate some java.lang and java.io classes, e.g. OutputStream within GWT.

I have created a "super" package in my module and referenced it using super-source.

My package structure looks like

```
com/example/gwt/client
com/example/gwt/server
com/example/gwt/shared
com/example/gwt/super
com/example/gwt/super/java/io/OutputStream.java
com/example/gwt/mymodule.get.xml
```

and mymodule.xml contains an entry

`<super-source path="super" />`

Within Eclipse all of the files within the super folder are in error - to be expected because the package structure is wrong. .class files are being generated in the WEB-INF/classes folder, again with the "wrong" package structure so should be ignored.

When I run my application in development mode I get lots of

`unable to resolve class java/lang/Object`

errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the approach - just the execution.

I had compile errors in the emulated classes which were being masked by the fact that Eclipse was showing errors because of the "incorrect" package structure. Running the compiler from within Eclipse flushed these out.

It also seems that deleting the gwt-unitCache might have helped. As I was moving code around it seems that there were stale entries in here that were still being referenced.

Comment: Hi Pauli, I'm having the exact same problem, but i'm already running the GWT compile from Eclipse and I'm getting [ERROR] Line 1: The declared package ... does not match the expected package ... . Why is the compiler having trouble realizing that the class is in a super-source package ?

Answer (score 1):

Rename ....get.xml to ....gwt.xml?

You can exclude "super" from the eclipse build path. 
Try right-clicking or the build path menu exclusion options..

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo when asking the question.

Comment: Can you post the full .gwt.xml? Perhaps missing an essential inherits there?